# .desktop File not Working Properly

Tags: python, chmod, desktop, python3, .desktop

I'm trying to create a `.desktop` file for a python script (for the Electrum Bitcoin wallet). If I navigate to the folder where the file is saved and run it (`python3 /home/username/.local/bin/electrum`), the app launches. However, my `electrum.desktop` file is not working for some reason. It looks as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Electrum

Comment=Lightweight Bitcoin Wallet.

GenericName=Bitcoin Wallet.

Exec=python3 /home/username/.local/bin/electrum

StartupNotify = true

Type=Application
```

I also ran `chmod u+x home/username/.local/bin/electrum` and `chmod u+x ~/Desktop/electrum.desktop`, and gave both files permission to be executed. `desktop-file-validate` is not returning any errors.
Now when I click the desktop icon, it simply opens the `.desktop` file in a text editor instead of running the application. I'm not super familiar with creating `.desktop` files; what did I do wrong?

Comment: see my question and answer here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/969231/17-10-18-04-tls-desktop-files-are-no-longer-trusted

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Although the accepted answer there didn't do anything (`gio: Error setting file metadata: No such file or directory`), your edit for Ubuntu 20.04 made me realize when I right click there's an option `allow launch` i.e. what you mean by `allow execution` I suppose. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I was searching for a command line only solution, anyway, glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution: it works by right-clicking the file on desktop and selecting `allow launch`.